# Appcelerator application throwing app.js not found on device

Tags: ios, xcode7, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

Recently I have upgraded all my iOS and Appcelerator kits to latest versions, and since then I have problems while preparing archive / builds.

Initially the app was throwing error on simulator but I found a way to resolve this.

Plz note I am using Xcode instead of Appcelerator for building archives

The steps I took to run the app successfully in simulator...

```
1. Xcode->Preferences->locations
2. Derived Data -> Advanced -> Custom: Relative to Workspace
3. Now build in Xcode it should not have that problem.
```

Now build is working fine in simulator, but I can still see app.js not found error on the device (I build the archive and installed via iTunes)

Thanks in advance... People having experience in using Xcode 7 may reply to this in a better way.

Comment: "Initially the app was throwing error on simulator but I found a way to resolve this." please explian...

Comment: why aren't you using Appcelerator Studio or the CLI?

Comment: yes on simulator I take 3 steps explained above in the question... and then it started working, but not on device

Comment: why aren't you using Appcelerator Studio or the CLI? -->> Actually from latest Appcelerator studio that's not possible with free subscription.

Comment: so you should use the CLI to compile and run. I suggest having a look at this article about Titanium OSS and Atom: https://github.com/m1ga/titanium_with_atom/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

This is an known issue:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19818

Please use Appcelerator's JIRA to report and track bugs.

And as people have commented, you should not actually need to build form Xcode as the CLI and Studio will do this for you via the Xcode command line.

Comment: We need to embed Extensions via Xcode as Appcelerator will not pick them up no matter what we do - which currently means we cannot archive at all using Xcode 7.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was because we were using camelCase as the project name "I think!!!"